# how to ensure python version is picked from /usr/bin/python

Tags: python, shell, posix

I have the following in my shell script ,i have a python version present in  /prj/qct/asw/SA/Linux which is overwriting the default one /usr/bin/python,how do I 
ensure python version is picked from /usr/bin/python with still exporting the KWTOOLS_DIR ?

```
export KWTOOLS_DIR=${KWTOOLS_DIR:-"/prj/qct/asw/SA/Linux"}
export PATH=${KWTOOLS_DIR}/Klocwork/Server/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that the path of your python installation appears earliest in the PATH,

```
export KWTOOLS_DIR=${KWTOOLS_DIR:-"/prj/qct/asw/SA/Linux"}
export PATH=$PATH:${KWTOOLS_DIR}/Klocwork/Server/bin
```

or you could use environment management tools such as [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).  I'd suggest the latter as it helps you isolate your python installations and the various dependency sets you might have for a given python install or version.

You can also start your individual scripts with the version you want to use:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

More detail on that route is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128669/python-script-header)

other questions posed slightly differently but that might have the same answers:

[regarding usr/bin/env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705/python-deployment-and-usr-bin-env-portability?rq=1)

[usage of #!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script?rq=1)

[more usage of #!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879569/usr-bin-python-and-usr-bin-env-python-which-support?rq=1)

Comment: how to ensure the path of your pythoninstallation appears firt..can we do export on the path before the KWTOOLS_DIR ?please suggest exact script changes

Comment: edited with script adjustment. append to end instead.

Comment: this super user question might be helpful as well: http://superuser.com/questions/238987/how-does-unix-search-for-executable-files

Comment: willthe following work?export KWTOOLS_DIR=${KWTOOLS_DIR:-"/prj/qct/asw/SA/Linux"}
export PATH=$PATH:${KWTOOLS_DIR}/Klocwork/Server/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to append `/usr/bin/python` to the end of the path; `/usr/bin` should already be on your path.  And if it wasn't then this puts `/usr/bin/python` after the `KWTOOLS_DIR`.